# Custom table cell on click method not firing when cell is added programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I am trying to make a custom calendar user control in .Net v4. For this control i have made a custom ASP table cell which has an onclick event. Class below:

```
public class ClickableTableCell : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    private static readonly object TableCellClicked = new object();

    public event EventHandler Click
    {
        add 
        { 
            base.Events.AddHandler(TableCellClicked, value); 
        }
        remove 
        { 
            base.Events.RemoveHandler(TableCellClicked, value); 
        }
    }

    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        string argument = null;

        if (this.ID != null)
        {
            argument = this.ID.ToString().Replace("/", "-");
        }

        Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, argument));
        base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
    }

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        OnClick(new EventArgs());
    }

    protected void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)base.Events[TableCellClicked];

        if (handler != null) 
        { 
            handler(this, e); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method in my user control which creates this table using my custom table cell. This method is fired in the page load of the user control so that the table is always populated. The same ID is always assigned to the clickable table cell however the click event that I set it to is never fired. Well it is fired when I declare the clickable table cell in the ASCX file, it doesn’t work if I add it programmatically, so i don't think there is anything wrong with my table cell class.

```
protected void DrawMonth(DateTime monthToDraw, CultureInfo calCulture)
    {
        try
        {
            tblCal.Rows.Clear();

            System.Globalization.Calendar calToDraw = calCulture.Calendar;

            DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = calCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

            //Add in day headings
            TableHeaderRow dayHeadings = new TableHeaderRow();

            int dayToStartFrom = (int)firstDayOfWeek;

            for (int iDay = 0; iDay < 7; iDay++)
            {
                TableHeaderCell dayCell = new TableHeaderCell();

                dayCell.ID = "tcDayHeader" + iDay;
                dayCell.Text = calCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[dayToStartFrom];

                dayCell.Width = new Unit(14.28, UnitType.Percentage);

                dayHeadings.Cells.Add(dayCell);

                dayToStartFrom++;

                if (dayToStartFrom > 6)
                {
                    dayToStartFrom = 0;
                }
            }

            tblCal.Rows.Add(dayHeadings);

            //Add in dates
            int startOffset = (int)calToDraw.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(monthToDraw.Year, monthToDraw.Month, 1).AddDays(-1));
            int endOffset = (int)calToDraw.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(monthToDraw.Year, monthToDraw.Month, calToDraw.GetDaysInMonth(monthToDraw.Year, monthToDraw.Month)));
            if (endOffset > 0)
            {
                endOffset = 7 - (int)calToDraw.GetDayOfWeek(new DateTime(monthToDraw.Year, monthToDraw.Month, calToDraw.GetDaysInMonth(monthToDraw.Year, monthToDraw.Month)));
            }
            int dateOn = 1;

            int numOfWeeks = Helpers.DateHelper.GetNumOfWeeksInMonth(monthToDraw, calToDraw);

            DateTime cellDate;

            for (int iNumWeek = 0; iNumWeek <= numOfWeeks - 1; iNumWeek++)
            {
                TableRow weekRow = new TableRow();
                weekRow.ID = "rowWeek" + iNumWeek.ToString();

                for (int iNumDayInWeek = 0; iNumDayInWeek <= 6; iNumDayInWeek++)
                {
                    ClickableTableCell dayCell = new ClickableTableCell();

                    if (iNumWeek == 0)
                    {
                        if (iNumDayInWeek < startOffset)
                        {
                            dayCell.CssClass = "OutOfBounds";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dayCell.Text = dateOn.ToString();

                            dateOn++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (iNumWeek == numOfWeeks - 1)
                    {
                        if (iNumDayInWeek > 6 - endOffset)
                        {
                            dayCell.CssClass = "OutOfBounds";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dayCell.Text = dateOn.ToString();

                            dateOn++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dayCell.Text = dateOn.ToString();

                        dateOn++;
                    }

                    dayCell.Width = new Unit(14.28, UnitType.Percentage);

                    if (monthToDraw.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && monthToDraw.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && (dateOn - 1) == DateTime.Now.Day)
                    {
                        dayCell.CssClass = "Today";
                    }

                    //  Get calendar data
                    if (dayCell.CssClass != "OutOfBounds")
                    {
                        cellDate = monthToDraw.AddDays((monthToDraw.Day * -1) - 1 + dateOn).Date;
                        dayCell.ID = cellDate.ToString().Replace(' ', '-');
                    }

                    //  add click event to the TableCell
                    dayCell.Click += new EventHandler(this.DayClicked);
                    dayCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'");

                    //  add cell to collection
                    weekRow.Cells.Add(dayCell);
                }

                tblCal.Rows.Add(weekRow);
            }

            lblCurrentMonth.Text = calCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[monthToDraw.Month - 1] + " " + monthToDraw.Year.ToString();

            tblCal.CssClass = "AppointCal";
        }
        catch (Exception _exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(_exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Interestingly if I place this code in the page load it will trap the click.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
   //It is a postback so check if it was by div click 
   string target = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
   if (target.Contains("ctl00$cphContent$amaAppointmentsCal$"))
   {
            //ClickableTableCell clickedCell = (ClickableTableCell)sender;
            string id = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
            DrawDay(Convert.ToDateTime(id), new CultureInfo("en-GB"));

   }
}
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please **do not** use the `asp` tag for `asp.net` questions.

Answer (score 0):

What does the html output look like for the table and customer table cell?

Comment: This what a typical cell will look like from the HTML source <td id="cphContent_amaAppointmentsCal_16/11/2011-00:00:00"
                    onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick=
                    "__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$amaAppointmentsCal$16/11/2011-00:00:00','16-11-2011-00:00:00')"
                    style="width:14.28%;">
                      16
                    </td>